# Could not print the temporary variable in the shell command

Tags: linux, sh, echo, temporary

I was trying to print the temporary variable in the shell command, but I only got four empty line.

```
/bin/sh -c "for i in {1..4}; do echo "$i"; done"
```

My sh version is GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release.
The format follows this [tutorial](https://www.shellscript.sh/loops.html).

Comment: Single quote the content of `-c` as `-c '...'`

Comment: Additionally POSIX shell doesn't provide brace-expansion of `{1...4}`. Use `n=1; while [ "$n" -le 4 ]; do echo "$i"; done` Bash does. If you want to use bash, then `/bin/bash -c "...` (or simply `bash -c "...` since `/bin/` is in the default path.)

Comment: what's the point of using `-c` here?

Comment: To treat everything that follows the shell invocation as the command to interpret.